# How to plot a function containing $\pm$ and unlimited solutions $n$?

Tags: function-construction

I have $$y=n\pi\pm\arcsin(\sin(x)), n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

How can one define and plot such a function in *Mathematica* for multiple $n$ at the same time?

Comment: You could use `Plot[]` and `Table[]`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility:

```
y[x_, n_Integer] := n Pi + {-1, 1} ArcSin[Sin[x]]
Plot[y[x, 3], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's another approach, in case you want the two "branches" to have different color:

```
With[{n = 3},
 Plot[Evaluate[n Pi + {-1, 1} ArcSin[Sin[x]]], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you use `Evaluate` you get the two colors, as shown; if, instead, you leave the `Evaluate` off, then the output is the same as the first one at the top.

Or you could use `Table`, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to have $n\to\infty$ instead of $n=3$?

Comment: @ImreVégh Since a finite machine (e.g., a computer, even with *Mathematica*) cannot enumerate infinitely many things, I'm wondering what you mean by $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Is it a limit? Or do you just want to pick a larger value for `n`?  Or maybe `Plot[Evaluate@Flatten[Table[n Pi + {-1, 1} ArcSin[Sin[x]], {n, 100}]], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]`?